# ADB push failed with Windows Cmder Terminal

Tags: cmder

Issue related to reported error [#1121](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1121). Does the error can be avoided by any other means?

The suggested change is not working for me - conversion of bash script to bat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional escape character can be added to avoid the error. My bad!

```
adb push --sync -p "issues.txt" "//sdcard" 2>&1
```